# is it possible to get address and private key from mnemonic code?

Tags: mnemonic

I have question

Is it possible to get address and private key from mnemonic code??

For example)
I created address (0x12345) and I receive mnemonic code such as apple bed bad rice

If i know mnemonic code (apple bed bad rice),
Can i get 0x12345 address ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes this is possible via [ethers.js](https://docs.ethers.io/ethers.js/html/index.html). Run the following piece of code in nodejs environment:

```
const ethers = require('ethers');

async function init() {
    //creating new random mnemonic
    //const mnemonic = await ethers.utils.HDNode.entropyToMnemonic(ethers.utils.randomBytes(16));
    const mnemonic = 'YOUR_MNEMONIC_WORDS';

    //mnemonic to private, public key and address
    const wallet = ethers.Wallet.fromMnemonic(mnemonic);
}
init();
```

If you need this logic on website you will have to use [browserify](http://browserify.org/), because browsers don't have the require method defined.