# Generate private keys from seed phrase

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle, mnemonic

I am working with @truffle/hdwallet-provider library.

This library works with a mnemonic. Is is basically a seedphrase.

Is there a way to work with this library outside truffle ? (I mean in a standalone javascript file).

Is there a way to calculate private keys from the mnemonic ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Re: Is there a way to work with this library outside truffle ?**

From the docs: *You can use this provider wherever a Web3 provider is needed, not just in Truffle.*

**Re: Is there a way to calculate private keys from the mnemonic ?**

I checked @truffle/hdwallet-provider docs and I didn't find such logic. I think this library is provider just for signing transactions, but you can achieve the mnemonic private key generation via ethers.js. I've explained how to do this [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/76880/is-it-possible-to-get-address-and-private-key-from-mnemonic-code/76882#76882).